# What do you Need for Windows Authentication Pass through on an MVC website and WCF

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, windows-authentication, pass-through

Ok.  I have an MVC2 application that accesses a WCF program, and uses that information to populate its model and so forth.  I am unsure of everything I need to get this through?  I have Impersonation code in my client application (MVC2 application) and in my Server application (WCF service).  On my IIS 7 setup (on windows server 2008) I have Anonymous Authentication disabled, ASP.net impersonation Enabled, and Windows Authentication enabled.  I have my process model pool identity set to ApplicationPoolIdentity.  I thought that should probably do it.  However, I keep getting errors telling me that the user ID is not going through.  I guess, I want to know is what would you need to get that sort of application to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your MVC App make sure your web config contains the following

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Also note that IIS has authentication options on each tree node for websites, so for instance if you use the Default Web Site and have your app under this node the authentication options can differ between the top node and the node for your site. For my site I have all auth methods turned off for the default web site node and then I use windows authentication only on the app level node. Make sure anonymous is turned off on all nodes or httpcontext.current.user object will be null and in our case caused our app to crash.

Switching authentication modes does inherit so be careful when adjusting parent nodes because you may accidentally change the settings of child nodes.

Comment: Should that be an authentication setting for one of the bindings, are is that another authentication setting.  Forgive my ignorance, I am a little new at this... :-)  Oh, you did say MVC app, and service.  I guess I was hoping that is what you meant, because I do not have that in my service, but it is in my MVC app.

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't specify that too clearly. The above setting will go in your web.config file that exists in the root directory of your MVC app. I guess the first thing we need to know is where the user is not coming through to, try going to the form load of your first page and check the HttpContext.Current.User to see if this object is null. If it is, you're mvc app is not authenticating. If it is service related you will need to impersonate the client on the service. There is pretty good documentation on how to do this here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090.aspx

Comment: I think I may have resolved this issue on my test server by following this advice.